# Support of multiple 3d formats in engine

Tags: 3d, models, file-format, model-loader

What is the best practice to add support of loading models from multiple file formats (.obj, .3ds ...)?
What class hierarchy should I use (now I have Mesh class( containing vertex, data ) and MeshLoader class ( doing nothing right now ))? 
I do not want to write loaders by myself, so than I have to copy loaded data into my structure.
Possibly you can show some articles explaining it especially Mesh class organization. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at Assimp? http://assimp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format that you load into your game engine should be specific to your game engine, and by specific I mean optimized for your target performance. What you will likely want to do, if you want to support multiple model formats, is to have a processing tool that will convert the different formats into the one for your engine. This is the start of an asset pipeline :)

Comment: This, but please don't force them to precompile everything ala XNA :/

Comment: @ClassicThunder Very true, especially if you want to target modding and such as I hear this is a right pain to accomplish with out visual studio to compile ala XNA.

Comment: You should hear the Terraria modding guys whine :)

Comment: @ClassicThunder That was actually the people I was thinking of when I was writing that ;)